# Git total number of deleted lines and added lines for complete log

Tags: git, refactoring, statistics, git-log

I am trying to visualize some code smells in our codebase. Basically this is what I would like to show:

- Top 20 of files by number of commits they occur in. This can be found using this command:

  ```
  $ git log --pretty=format: --name-only | sort | uniq -l | sort -rg | head -20
  ```
- Top 20 files by added lines. Don't know how to get this, and I also want to omit the first commit in this count, as it will not make much sense to show the number of lines added when we moved from SVN.
- Top 20 files by deleted lines. Don't know how to get this.
- Top 20 files by changed (including added and deleted) lines. Don't know how to get this.

I will hold these counts up against the number of lines of code in each of these files.

The added and deleted lines I can sort of get with this command:

```
$ git log --numstat --pretty --oneline <filename> | awk 'N F==3 {plus+=$1; minus+=$2} END {printf("+%d, -%d\n", plus, minus)}'
```

But the added lines is skewed because I cannot omit the first commit. Also I want it to analyse the entire codebase and not just one file.

What I plan to visualize is a suspicion I have, which is that the largest files we have, will also be the ones that we change the most, and therefore they are prime candidates for refactoring. I have no interest in who made what changes or who deleted or added most lines. I just want to make a painful point to some of the decision makers ;-)

This is inspired by Michael Feathers, who at QCon talked about exactly this.

Can anyone help me with the remaining parts?

Answer (score 0):

Find the hash of the first-commit-after-big-migration, or add a tag to it, and use it in your `git log` command  :

```
$ git log --numstat --pretty --oneline 0f5d22e..HEAD -- <filename> | awk ...
```

Comment: I tried that already... and just now realized that I had reversed the two commits I wanted to check between ;-) But anywho... when I do this, then I still get a crazy big number of added lines, and that isn't right! I get +2.08e+39 added lines, and that is nowhere close to being true!